# JS function included in the file is not getting invoked?

Tags: javascript, html, struts2, struts

Javascript function included in `history.js` is not getting invoked in the Struts 2 jsp page when I select an item in the dropdown box.

This is the error I saw it in developer tools

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: getClasses is not defined
    at HTMLSelectElement.onchange (history.action:279)
```

This is how included in jsp page

```
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/struts-tags.tld" prefix="s"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<s:url value='/js/common/ajax.js'/>"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<s:url value='/js/common/sorttable.js'/>"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<s:url value='/js/common/CalendarPopup.js'/>"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<s:url value='/js/common/skuformatting.js'/>"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<s:url value='/js/common/formatsku.js'/>"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<s:url value='/js/history.js'/>"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var cal = new CalendarPopup();      
</script>
...
...
<td align="center"> 
    <s:select id="form.search.deptFilter"  property="form.search.deptFilter" 
     list="form.deptSelectList" onchange="getClasses()" size="5"
     listKey="name" listValue="value" headerKey="-1" headerValue="Select a Department" />
</td>
...
```

`getClasses()` is defined in `history.js` and here is the method definition inside that file.

```
...
    function getClasses(){
        var selectionComponent = document.getElementById('form.search.deptFilter');
        if(selectionComponent.options[selectionComponent.selectedIndex].value == -1)
            return;
        clearSubClasses();
        document.getElementById('form.search.classFilter').options.length = 0;  // Empty class select box
        sendAjaxRequest(selectionComponent,createClass);
    }
...
```

One thing I noticed in sources section of developer tools, I don't see all the js files included in the jsp page in js folder which I think is the problem but not sure why. But couple of weeks back, things were working fine.

Any idea why the js method present in the `history.js` file is not getting invoked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is your JSP page generate an invalid HTML. When loading it still invoke an order of it's elements. However `<script>` tags invoke in a separated thread by the browser asynchronously.

And document loading doesn't wait for them to finish. Hense, you have not defined reference to the function because this function is not loaded yet. To make sure you define a function before you use it in the document you should use document ready event.

The usual practice if you create a document with `<head>` and `<body>` tags, and put your `<script>` tags inside the `<head>`. All functions defined in the `<head>` are available to the `<body>` elements.

Comment: Thanks Roman for your response . I have the head and body tags inside the base layout jsp which we render using tiles 2. It was working few weeks back but with more changes being made since then, something caused this to stop working.

Comment: @ramkris Then you should compare what you have now with what you had then to see what the differences are. Check the JS console for JS errors. Check the network tab for the JS file requests and their HTTP codes. Check the rendered HTML for their inclusion and paths. If it “used to work” and now doesn’t showing us the unchanged code won’t help.

Comment: @ramkris If you still have problems with the code then you can rollback your changes and it will start working again. Saying that "something caused this to stop working" doesn't help. What did you do to resolve your problem? Tiles has nothing to do with JS, and you didn't post any Tiles code. It is just a simple JS error which should debuged in the browser.

Comment: I reverted all the code changes to one month back and now I see it working.. Thank you all for your comments